# How can I save a string with spaces to a file that should also be apart of a parallel array

Tags: arrays, c, string, file

```
int main (){
    int id[ms],qid,score[ms],oscores[ms],menu,age[ms],nstud,i, dob[ms],a;
    float stime[ms],ttime1[ms], cyctime[ms],ttime2[ms],runtime[ms],otime[ms];
    float koswin = 0, ikidswin = 0, ciwin = 0, swimwin = 0, cycwin = 0, runwin =0;
    char name[100][ms], sc[100][ms], etype[ms], gender [ms], kwin, iwin, 
    cwin,word[100],pname[100],psc[100];
    FILE *fh;
    FILE *fp;
    fh=fopen("participants.txt","a");

    printf("Would you like to:\n");
    printf("1.Register participants\n");
    printf("2.Access a participant's details\n");
    scanf("%d",&menu);
    system("cls");

    if (menu == 1)
    {
        printf("Please enter number of participants you would like to register\n");
        scanf("%d",&nstud);
        for (i = 0; i < nstud; i++){
            printf("Please enter the the ID number of the participant:\n");
            scanf("%d",&id[i]);
            printf("Please enter the participant's name:\n");
           fgets(pname, sizeof(pname), stdin);
            strcpy(sc[i], pname);
            printf("Please enter the participant's School/Club:\n");
            fgets(psc, sizeof(psc), stdin);
            strcpy(sc[i], psc);
            
        }
        for (i= 0; i < nstud; i++ )
        fprintf(fh,"\n%d\t\n%s\t",id[i],name[i]);
        fclose(fh);

    }
```

The code works up until I am to enter the name it skips over the name and goes to the school input but it doesn't even accept the school name. It continues by skipping another input. I first had scanf("%s", name[i]) and scanf("%s", sc[i]) and that worked perfectly but I wanted the user to be able to enter a space. So is there a way to accept a string that is apart of a parallel array with space and write it to a file?

Comment: What is a "parallel array"? Also, please show your exact run log.

Comment: `fprintf(fh,"\n%d\t\n%s\t",id[i],name[i]);` That looks wrong. The contents of `name` have never been set and hence contains indeterminate values. Treating it as a string results in Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: `int id[ms]` What is `ms`? It is not shown. Please provide complete code as a [mre].

Comment: #define ms 1024

Comment: it is the max size

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Comment: Best to drop `scanf()` everywhere and use `fgets()` to read user input.

Answer (score 0):

The entry of the name looks skipped because the previous `scanf()`
for the entry of ID leaves the newline character in the input buffer
and the fgets() for the name reads it.
To avoid this, modify the line:

```
scanf("%d",&id[i]);
```

to

```
scanf("%d%*c",&id[i]);
```

to flush the input buffer.

Comment: Note: `"*c"` in `"%d%*c"` consumes the next character after the number - it _might_ be a `'\n'`.  `scanf("%d%*c",&id[i]);` consumes nothing if the first part is not numeric text.